# android studio can not see emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter

I am new in a flutter when I create my project in an android studio and try to run it but the android studio can not see the emulator event I had run emulator like this picture.
[image]

and I already install android SDK like this

[image]

please help me if any of you know how to solve the issue.
thank you!

Comment: Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
     ANDROID_HOME = C:\src\android-sdk but Android SDK not found at this location.

Comment: Well, is C:\src\android-sdk the folder where your Android SDK exists?